# Is there an equivalent of " ... || die" in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Kind of like `<statement> || die` in perl, something concise that I can put with every critical statement to avoid bothering powershell with the rest of the script if something goes wrong.

Comment: usualy, the $ErrorPreferenceVariable is set to 'stop' and a try/catch structure is used to handle the errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most commands support the `-ErrorAction` common parameter.  Specifying `-ErrorAction Stop` will generally halt the script on an error.  See `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`.

By default, `-ErrorAction` is `Continue`.  You can change the default option by changing the value of `$ErrorActionPreference`.  See `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`.

If verbosity is really an issue, `-ErrorAction` is aliased to `-ea`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement a `...|| die`-like construct in PowerShell without the need to add huge try-catch constructs, would be to use the automatic variable `$?`.
From [`Get-Help about_Automatic_variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

```
$?  
   Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
   TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.
```

Simply add the following right after each critical statement:

```
if(-not $?){
    # Call Write-EventLog or write $Error[0] to an xml or txt file if you like
    Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: @Lyt_Seeker You're very welcome ^_^ Please consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: Back then, a solution like that by Bacon Bits worked for me; 
I have used $? later for other things, but his answer was solved it for me. Thanks for your inputs here again!